# Javascript is popup with focus is not opening again after closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the onclick function with window.open popup, the popup comes to front with the same button, but after closing it is not opening again

```js
<Button hideLabel aria-label={zxxxx "}
    className = {styles.button}
    icon = "plus"
    color = "danger"
    size = "lg"
    circle
    onClick = {
      () => {
        if (!this.state.isOpened) {
          this.setState({
            isOpened: true
          })
          var mywin = window.open("https://app.mural.co", "MsgWindow", "width=1366,height=768")
          mywin.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
            this.setState({
              isOpened: true
            })
          }, false)
          this.setState({
              windows: mywin
            }

            this.setState(mywin)
          }
          else {
            const window = this.state.windows;
            if (window) {
              window.focus();
            }

          }
        }
      }/>
```

Comment: `aria-label={zxxxx "}` does not look correct

Comment: Also this `this.setState({ windows: mywin } this.setState(mywin)}`

Comment: please don't tag javascript questions as java. It might confuse those who assume you are asking something related to java. Java and javascript are (a bit) alike in name and syntax only, but that's about it.

Comment: @Stultuske sorry for that bro ,

Comment: the label is no problem ,THe windows open is the one ,After opening  and closing the popup ,it does not  open up again ,is there any was i cant rectify the mistake

Comment: There are typos in the definition. Any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your code. Please refer to the commented line.

```js
     if (!this.state.isOpened) {
          this.setState({
            isOpened: true
          })
          var mywin = window.open("https://app.mural.co", "MsgWindow", "width=1366,height=768")
          mywin.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
            this.setState({
              isOpened: true
            })
          }, false)
          this.setState({ // there is no closing parenthesis for this
              windows: mywin
            }

            this.setState(mywin)
          }
          else {
            const window = this.state.windows;
            if (window) {
              window.focus();
            }

          }
        }
```

Moreover `aria-label={zxxxx "}` also is missing something. I would highly recommend a code editor that points out these errors for you.

Comment: I already pointed that out. Please do not answer typos that are already mentioned in comments to the question